# How to select data in a single query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hope you all will be fine
I have a problem like this.
A class of students have taken exams .
Now I want to select top 3 position holder getting highiest marks.
Now situation is that .. if there are two students getiing 100 marks, one is getting 99 marks and 1 is getting 98 marks, then tere are four students on top 3 positions

```
Student1 = 100 marks at first position
Student2 = 100 marks at first position
Student3 = 99 marks at second position
Student4 = 98 marks at thirs position
```

How can i get these four students for first three positions
If I use query
Select top 3 MonthlyPremium from insurant order by MonthlyPremium desc
then it reurns top 3 rows i.e.

```
Student1 = 100 marks (who is at first position)
Student2 = 100 marks (who is at first position)
Student3 = 99 marks (who is at second position)
while the student4 = 98 at third poistion is missing.
```

Can any body tell me the right query to select all these students.
Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SqlServer.....

Comment: Why are you copying all of your questions from other forums: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=82627 ?

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Student,Marks,Rank from (
Select Student,
       Marks,
       Dense_Rank() Over(Order by Marks Desc) as Rank from TableName
    )t 
     where t.Rank<4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ( I am not sure about correctness of sql):

```
select * from students where students.mark in (select mark from students order by mark DESC LIMIT 3)
```

This query takes 3 top marks and than takes students that have only this marks

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE BookTitle (
 Id INT NOT NULL,
 NAME VARCHAR(60) NULL,
 Marks INT null
 )
 INSERT INTO BookTitle VALUES (1,'s',100) ,(2,'d',100) ,(3,'e',99),(4,'f',98)

SELECT B.* FROM BookTitle B WHERE 3>=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (A.Marks)) FROM  BookTitle A WHERE A.marks >=B.Marks)
```